# Redirect Page When Onclick Pushnotifications

Tags: ionic2

I am using FCM PLugin Ionic 2

Below my app component

```
   constructor(public menu1: MenuController,public alertCtrl:AlertController,public platform: Platform,public authservice:Authservice) {

      this.initializeApp();

  }


initializeApp() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();

      //Push Notifications

      if(typeof(FCMPlugin) !== "undefined")
      {
        FCMPlugin.getToken(function(t){
          console.log("Use this token for sending device specific messages\nToken: " + t);
        }, function(e){
          console.log("Uh-Oh!\n"+e);
        });
         FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(d){
          if(d.wasTapped){  
                            console.log(d);
            var nav:NavController = this.app.getComponent("nav");
            this.nav = nav;
            nav.setRoot(MycomplaintsPage);
} else {

            console.log("Push Notification", d);
            console.log("you have new notifications");
          }
        }, function(msg){
                      }, function(err){
          console.log("Arf, no good mate... " + err);
        });
      }
```

}

It's work Perfectly.But Click on Notifications Page cannot redirect.

I am getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponent' of undefined.

How to fix this issue.

Kindly Advice me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `this` object changes if you use regular functions i.e it belongs to the function not the class so `this.app` is nor defined. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `()=>{}` doesn't define `this` and the outer `this` is used.
Use arrow functions for callbacks

```
 FCMPlugin.onNotification((d)=>{
          if(d.wasTapped){  
                            console.log(d);
            var nav:NavController = this.app.getComponent("nav");
            this.nav = nav;
            nav.setRoot(MycomplaintsPage);
            //...
         });
```

Or set `self=this` before the call and use `self`.

```
let self = this.//declare here

 FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(d){
          if(d.wasTapped){  
                            console.log(d);
            var nav:NavController = self.app.getComponent("nav");//use here
            this.nav = nav;
            nav.setRoot(MycomplaintsPage);
            //...
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Where to set self.I dont understand.Please explain;

Comment: I used this.But i am getting this error Property getComponent does not exist type on App.

Comment: what is `app` variable of? and can you show `getComponent()` in the question?

Comment: I declare app variable public app: App; and  import { Nav,NavController,Platform,App} from 'ionic-angular';

Comment: if you are importing you should inject it in constructor not declare it..`App` is not a global object

Comment: I Inject constructor in public app:App and does not declare global object.But Still I am get the same error.any other way to page redirect on Click notifications

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/app/App/#getActiveNav use `this.app.getActiveNav()` or `this.app.getRootNav()` depending on your logic..I think it should be rootnav but cant be certain

Comment: I Reffered this link.I set var nav:NavController = this.app.getActiveNav() ;But still Geting this error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getActiveNav' of undefined.Why i am getting this error still now?