# Ionic 2 Push Notifications with FCM

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm implementing Push Notifications on my Android Ionic 2 App with the [Ionic Native FCM](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/)

When I'm receiving a notification in the foreground it works, but when I'm receiving a notification in the background and if I clicked on it, nothing happens.

**app.component.ts**

```
firebaseInit(){
  //Firebase
  this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');

  this.fcm.getToken()
    .then(token => {
      console.log(token);
      this.nativeStorage.setItem('fcm-token', token);
  });

  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("NOTIF DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      if(data.wasTapped){
        this.nav.push(MemoViewPage, {memo: {_id: data.memo_id}})
        console.info('Received in bg')
      }else{
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: data.subject,
          message: "New memorandum",
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Ignore',
              role: 'cancel'
            },
            {
              text: 'View',
              handler: () => {
                this.nav.push(MemoViewPage, {memo: {_id: data.memo_id}})
              }
            }
          ]
        });

        alert.present();
        console.info('Received in fg')
      }
  });

  this.fcm.onTokenRefresh()
    .subscribe(token => {
      console.log(token);
  })
}
```

The `if(data.wasTapped)` condition doesn't go off once I clicked the notification from the system tray.

**EDIT**

The app opens but only in the Home Page not to the designated page that I set which is `this.nav.push(MemoViewPage, {memo: {_id: data.memo_id}})`

I also cannot receive notifications when the app is killed or not running.

Comment: You should use `NavController` for the app to open to a specific page.

Comment: Also you could use local push notification instead of FCM, which is much better in my experiance

Comment: @KevinRED NavController doesn't work inside app.component.ts it says that there is no provider and I get an error when inserting NavController under app.module.ts

Comment: Just import from ionic-angular, just the way you import nav

Comment: `import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular'`

Comment: @KevinRED still getting the error. Here is my import ```import { Nav, Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';``` Here is the constructor ```              public navCtrl: NavController, ```

Comment: What is the error, can you tell the error?

Comment: No provider for NavController

Comment: okay. Can you use App, then?

Comment: `import {App} from 'ionic-angular';      `                                                                           `this.app.getActiveNav().push(MyPage);`

Comment: What do you mean can I use App? The app is not loading, just gives me a white screen.

Comment: Please use the import `App` just like I mentioned in replace with `nav`

Comment: It only opens the app and does not navigate to the MemoViewPage

Comment: which page is it going?

Comment: It only goes to my HomePage

Comment: Can you give me sometime to recreate the scenario. Let me have a look at it

Comment: can you refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759668/redirect-page-when-onclick-pushnotifications/42759731?noredirect=1#comment72636100_42759731

Comment: also this https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/269

Comment: @KevinRED I solved the issue by sending the notification with the click_action: FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY parameter. My last problem is that I'm not receiving notifications when the app is killed or not running

Comment: I believe there is something you can do in the server side of the script,  can you look into this link for more info  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#background-notifications

Comment: @KevinRED I tried all of the following options with the link you have given. I still don't receive notifications when the app is killed. I've searched for tutorials regarding this but they only show you how to receive in the background and foreground

Comment: Do you have the option to replace FCM plugin with push plugin? Can you do that?

Comment: Will update you on this. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinRED updated the code using the push plugin but I cannot receive any notifications. I followed the Push Native docs in setting it up.

Comment: I had updated the notification in my answer, and also what service you are using to send a notification in to your device?

Comment: I'm using the firebase http request to this endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` @KevinRED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `push` plugin instead of `FCM`.

```
this.push.createChannel({
 id: "testchannel1",
 description: "My first test channel",
 importance: 3
}).then(() => console.log('Channel created'));
```

and then you could use pushObjects to specify the needs for your notification like sound, ion etc.

```
const options: PushOptions = {
   android: {},
   ios: {
       alert: 'true',
       badge: true,
       sound: 'false'
   },
   windows: {},
   browser: {
       pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
   }
};
```

After that it is easy for you to receive notifications whether you are using the app or not

```
const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => this.nativeStorage.setItem('fcm-token', token));

pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));
```

you could use the option of `forceShow:true` in the `pushObject init`  for the app to show the notification whether you are using the app or not.

And once you clicked the notification the notification payload is received by the app with the app home page set as default.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with the `pushObject.on('notification')` part of the code because I'm not getting any logs whenever I receive a notification

Comment: `pushObject.on('notification').subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log('Message: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
        if(data.additionalData.foreground){
          console.log('Received in fg')
        }else{
          console.log('Received in bg');
        }
    })`

Comment: I managed to solve the issue just by double checking the [documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#huawei-and-xiaomi-phones). Because I was testing the app using an Asus Phone and I just needed to allow the app to run in the background. I didn't have to use the phonegap-push-plugin

Comment: Hey great, for everything works right. Glad to help you